# Statsmodels "predict" function - why cant I predict out of sample? :(

Tags: python, prediction, statsmodels, forecast

I have fitted a multiple linear regression model using statsmodels OLS with 4 inputs and wish to predict one month into the future. 
I can predict "into my test-set" and evaluate on the performance of my forecast, but when I try predicting into a specific time period outside my dataset nothing works.
This is the prediction into my test-set that works:

```
est = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train)
est2 = est.fit()
ypred = est2.predict(x_valid)
```

This is my best attempt to predict into a specific timeperiod outside my dataset:

```
start_index = datetime(2019, 12, 2)
end_index = datetime(2020, 1, 2)
forecast = est2.predict(start_index, end_index)
```

This is my error code:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (4,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Any help or references on where to find help is very highly valued.

Br and big thanks in advance

Comment: OLS assumes independent observations so a time sequence and time index does not have any special meaning for the model. Those are only supported in time series models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This clarifies why my attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the element of `x_valid` collections should have the same type as elements in the `x_train` collection. So you should:

1. Extract from the `x_valid` needed records based on date.
2. Call the predict method with extracted collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this mean I can't predict on dates where data on all my input parameters don't exist? So I cant in fact predict "into the future" using OLS?